# Running storybook in a project inside another project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vuejs2, migration, storybook

I have a project that is written in Vue2 and we are currently migrating to ReactJS. Our current approach for this is to have the following file structure:

```
 - Main_Project/
   - .storybook/
   - package.json
   - node_modules/
   - tsconfig.json
   - src/
     - utils/
       - style.ts
     - models/
       - User.ts
     - react_migration/
       - .storybook/
       - src/
       - package.json
       - tsconfig.json
       - node_modules/
```

This seems to be working great and we use a `ReactWrapper` component to put React code into our Vue components. The problem is, we have now installed storybook for the `react-migration` project which was working really well until we tried to import something from the `Main_Project`. The `Main_Project` has a path alias of `@/*` which points to its `src/` directory. When importing the `style.ts` file into a React component, it works fine in the browser, but Storybook has an issue with finding imported files inside of it. Line 1 of `style.ts` is:

```js
import { UserType } from "@/models/User"
```

Storybook seems to be able to find the `style.ts` file, but it doesn't know what to do with the `@/models/User`. I have tried to add the outer project as a dependency to the `react-migration` folder with:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "main": "file:../.."
}
```

to no avail. I also tried to create a workspace in the main projects `package.json` file.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to help storybook resolve the correct path alias in imported files?

Please and thank you in advance, and please let me know if any more information is needed :)